# The reason for the CombinedState type in redux's typescript types

Tags: typescript, redux

Redux has the following types:

```
declare const $CombinedState: unique symbol

/**
 * State base type for reducers created with `combineReducers()`.
 *
 * This type allows the `createStore()` method to infer which levels of the
 * preloaded state can be partial.
 *
 * Because Typescript is really duck-typed, a type needs to have some
 * identifying property to differentiate it from other types with matching
 * prototypes for type checking purposes. That's why this type has the
 * `$CombinedState` symbol property. Without the property, this type would
 * match any object. The symbol doesn't really exist because it's an internal
 * (i.e. not exported), and internally we never check its value. Since it's a
 * symbol property, it's not expected to be unumerable, and the value is
 * typed as always undefined, so its never expected to have a meaningful
 * value anyway. It just makes this type distinquishable from plain `{}`.
 */
export type CombinedState<S> = { readonly [$CombinedState]?: undefined } & S
```

I am a bit clueless as to what this symbol and type are used for.

An example usage is in `combineReducers`

```
export default function combineReducers<S>(
  reducers: ReducersMapObject<S, any>
): Reducer<CombinedState<S>>
export default function combineReducers<S, A extends Action = AnyAction>(
  reducers: ReducersMapObject<S, A>
): Reducer<CombinedState<S>, A>
export default function combineReducers<M extends ReducersMapObject<any, any>>(
  reducers: M
): Reducer<
  CombinedState<StateFromReducersMapObject<M>>,
  ActionFromReducersMapObject<M>
>
export default function combineReducers(reducers: ReducersMapObject) {
  const reducerKeys = Object.keys(reducers)
  const finalReducers: ReducersMapObject = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < reducerKeys.length; i++) {
    const key = reducerKeys[i]

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      if (typeof reducers[key] === 'undefined') {
        warning(`No reducer provided for key "${key}"`)
      }
    }

    if (typeof reducers[key] === 'function') {
      finalReducers[key] = reducers[key]
    }
  }
```

The comments say it used to distinguish it from `{}` or empty type but I don't see anywhere that it checks this type and it even says in the comments that internally we never check its value so why is it even in there apart from to confuse people like me?

Comment: What version are you using? It's not in the latest definitions. It's a trick to ensure nominal-like typing instead of what ts usually does which is structural typing.

Comment: it’s in master on github.  i’m sorry, i don’t know what nominal typing means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment mentions typescript is duck typed, this means that you can assign seemingly unrelated types one to another:

```
type A = { foo: string, baz?: string }
type B = { foo: string, goo?: number }

declare let a: A;
declare let b: B;

// Unrelated types, structurally compatible, so assignable
a = b;
b = a;
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUBmB7dAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gDRQBGAhgF4D8O+x5UAvgFCiRQBCCZGkwtCpSlDKZmUEgFcAttQgFOXLgBMIAYwA2tAtD0RgUWjhgBuLboNGoJs9Rz8bXAPQeoAVRJGDYAhNKF4IXCpWeR1geQJaPT0QKB10RTBaYCJqE0j0c1xcIjISWhyILlohahtqIVp3IA)

This behavior is called [structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) and is different from how other strongly typed languages (such as Java or C#) work. More traditional languages use [nominal typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), where the structure does not matter, and, baring some inheritance relationship, `A` would not be assignable to `B`.

To simulate something akin to nominal typing in typescript we can use either private fields or `unique symbol`s which do behave nominally. This means structure does not matter, when deciding compatibility, two `unique symbol`s are compatible only if they come from the same definition.

This means that for `CombinedState`, the type system will be able to guarantee that if a type `T extends { [$CombinedState]: undefined }` the it must have come from `combineReducers` (or at least it is an instantiation of `CombinedState`). This is guaranteed since `$CombinedState` is not accessible to clients so it's only usage would come from within the library.

Why is this important? Well probably, because of `PreloadedState`:

```
/**
 * Recursively makes combined state objects partial. Only combined state _root
 * objects_ (i.e. the generated higher level object with keys mapping to
 * individual reducers) are partial.
 */
export type PreloadedState<S> = Required<S> extends {
  [$CombinedState]: undefined
}
  ? S extends CombinedState<infer S1>
    ? {
        [K in keyof S1]?: S1[K] extends object ? PreloadedState<S1[K]> : S1[K]
      }
    : never
  : {
      [K in keyof S]: S[K] extends object ? PreloadedState<S[K]> : S[K]
    }
```

In `PreloadedState` the fact that `S` is a `CombinedState` triggers different behavior in the conditional type.